# Is it possible to have a windows desktop app with metro interface (or a metro app with no intention of going to the windows store)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, serial-port, desktop-application

Apologies for the noobish question, and I did try to search but couldn't find the right answer (or didn't search properly).

Currently have an app developed in a windows desktop environment because it gives us access to deeper features of the PC such as serial port comms etc. that the normal metro environment wouldn't allow. We're currently developing the UI based on metroUI so we can run it on an 8.1 touchscreen (metroUI looks good, gives us a touch-screen experience with PC features) but we have no intention of putting it on the marketplace.

Just wanted to confirm if this is in fact doable, and we can have this desktop application with a metro UI? Or is my noobishness meaning I'm overlooking some technical feasibility that makes it impossible?

Answer (score 2):

This is doable with the Windows 8.1 Update (from April 2014). It's not supported before that since Windows Store apps were blocked from communicating with desktop processes.

The Windows 8.1 Update adds a feature "Brokered Windows Runtime Components" designed to allow side-loaded Windows Store apps to communicate with a desktop back-end. This will allow your Windows Store app UI to call the desktop component to access API that aren't available in the limited app package environment.

See [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx) for details.

See [Try It Out: Sideload Windows Store Apps on](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) TechNet for how to enable side-loading on your systems. See [Windows 8.1 Update: Sideloading Enhancements](http://blogs.windows.com/itpro/2014/04/03/windows-8-1-update-sideloading-enhancements/) for updates on how to enable a system for sideloading (no license required when on a domain, and significantly easier to get a sideloading license for non-domain joined systems).

The developer license system is designed for development and test purposes only. You really don't want to use it for production. Use the proper enterprise side-loading system instead.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the whole point here is to make it look like a Windows Store app. If you're app is a WPF one, you can already use [Mahapps.metro](http://mahapps.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows Store app without going to the store by Sideloading it. You create an app package first. The user has to right click the .ps1 file in that package to see the option Run with PowerShell and install it in a very old fashioned DOS like manor. It will only run when the user has a Microsoft Developer License and renew it every month. However, it is not allowed to keep using a Developer License of the end user to run a Store app. In the end, the system has to be domain bound to be allowed to run these apps, or you have to buy a Enterprise Sideloading key. These come in packages of 100 for $ 3000,- or you can unlock all PC's for 1 client for $ 100-.

It would be nicer if the specific pros of a Store program were available in a desktop environment but with W10 coming up I do expect a bit more integration and less restrictions.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: The developer license system is designed for development and test purposes only. You really don't want to use it for production. Use the proper enterprise side-loading system instead. I'm having a bit of trouble parsing the details here, but the numbers given appear to be out of date. They may have been correct before April 2014, but not anymore.